# ANOVA on ranks confusion

Tags: anova

I just want to start off by saying I'm not good in stats at all, hence I'm using sigma plot/stat.

So I need to compare groups (with different sample sizes), and since they're not normally distributed, I'm using ANOVA on ranks. And I just realized that the results of the analysis is different depending on what groups I include in the test.
E.g.
If I test gp A, B, C, and D.
Dunn's post hoc pair-wise comparison says A is only different from B.
If I don't include gp D. Dunn's says A is different from B and C.

I also find that if I do ANOVA on ranks for many groups, Dunn's does not show sig. dif. between some pairs, but if I do Mann Whitney Rank Sum test on the pair, there is sig. dif.

So how can I keep things consistent/comparable? Can I just be stupid and do Mann Whitney on everything? (Like I said, I'm really bad at stats).

I'd appreciate any help or comments. Thanks so much!

Comment: No: Dunn's test preserves the ranking from a Kruskal-Wallis test, and employs a pooled variance for the pairwise tests that is appropriate to rank sums. Dunn's test does not in and of itself require Bonferroni (or any other) multiple comparison adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify the experimental design, so I assume that all comparisons are equally important.  Then use the Kruskal-Wallis rank ANOVA before doing any pairwise comparisons.  If this is significant you have more license in doing pairwise comparisons.  That brings up a common problem: Wilcoxon tests can be at odd with the unified Kruskal-Wallis analysis.  For that and to be able to handle covariates I am moving more and more to the generalization of the two tests: the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model.  With it you can do pairwise tests that are fully embedded in the overall model containing multiple groups.

Comment: Conceptually, I see how the GLM with cumulative logits and proportional odds can handle designs that are more general than those for Wilcoxon/Kruskal-Wallis. Do you have a good reference where the statistical side of this generalization is explained? I.e., that shows how the proportional odds model with associated tests reduces exactly/asymptotically (?) to the Wilcoxon/KW tests (similar to ANOVA -> t-test). Thanks!

Comment: I can't remember the best reference on this.  I think it's a paper by John Whitehead.  The best way to see it is to derive the score test for comparing two groups from the PO model.  The numerator of the score test is exactly the Wilcoxon test, and Kruskal-Wallis with two groups is the Wilcoxon test.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare A, B, and C you have 3 pairs to look at.  When you include D you have 6 possibe pairs.  If you added a few more groups then you would have even more pairs to compare.  When you have a large number of comparisons there is a higher chance of seeing something that looks like a difference but is just due to chance.  So multiple comparison procedures correct for this increased liklihood of seeing something due to chance by making the criteria for calling something significant stronger.

So the difference between A and C in your comparison is big enough to be considered significant (not likely due to chance) when there are 3 comparisons, but could be considered due to chance when there are 6 comparisons.  Since D was of interest you should keep the information on the possible comparisons with D and go with the stricter adjustment.

Consider if you saw a picture of a target with a bullet hole near the center and a note on the picture said that the shooter was 100 yards (or meters) away when the shot was taken.  This seems impresive, but now we zoom out and see that the target is on the side of a barn that is littered with hundreds of bullet holes and we see the shooter (who is 100 yards/meters away) holding a fully automatic machine gun and there are thousands of shells around them implying that fewer than half of the shots even hit the barn.  The fact that 1 of the bullets hit the target is much less impressive (significant) now, but if we had zoomed out to find the shooter had a single shot rifle and had hit the target with a single shot, that would stay impressive (significant).

Reporting results from the A, B, and C comparison when D had been looked at would be like showing a picture with 3 bullet holes, 2 of which hit the target, but cropping out the other 3 holes from other shots taken (comparisons with D).

Answer (score 1):

When the distributional assumptions of ANOVA—(1) normally distributed *variables*, and (2) equal variances—the Kruskal-Wallis test is an appropriate nonparametric omnibus test with the null hypothesis of no stochastic dominance among groups. If one additionally assumes that the shape of the distributions of outcomes is the same in each group, differing only by location, then the null hypothesis may be interpreted as equal medians.

The appropriate *post hoc* test in this situation is Dunn's Test. Were one to simply use pair-wise rank sum tests following rejection of a Kruskal-Wallis test, one would (1) create different ranks than were used in the Kruskal-Wallis test, and (2) not employ the pooled variance built into the null hypothesis. Family-wise error rate and false discovery rate adjustments for multiple comparisons may then be applied.

If you are using Stata, see `net describe dunntest, from(https://alexisdinno.com/stata)`.